# Cannot edit my 2 of my Custom Headers in IIS

Tags: windows-server-2016, iis-10, cors

I'm having a few problems that I hope you can help me with.

I have 2 web servers 2016, with IIS 10. And I've created a number of CORS on these Web Servers (Configuration Editor, system.webserver/httpprotocol, and customHeaders). In short, I have been able to create these security headers and I have been able to remove them, except on one of the web servers, where I have not been able to remove 2 of them (X-Frame-Options and Strict-Transport-Security). They appear as locked or shaded or something like that.

I'm freaking out about this problem. It doesn't seem logical to me that only happens on one of the 2 servers and I really need to update these Security Headers. Can you please give me a hand?

Many Thanks

[image]

Comment: CORS headers should be configured via IIS CORS module if you want to save yourself from the nightmares. "They appear as locked or shaded or something like that" isn't always true if you learn how IIS settings are layered and inherited at different levels, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8 Open `applicationHost.config` and the relevant `web.config` files, because they often show you more hints than IIS Manager.

Comment: Hi @LexLi. Great! It worked. I changed the values directly from the file and it was reflected on IIS - Configuration Editor section. If you want to answer my question I will rate it. Many Thanks